# How do I determine the network i am connected to in Ganache

Tags: blockchain, solidity, metamask, ganache

How do I connect determine the netwoek i amm connected to in Ganache

I tried this
const networkId = await Web3.eth.net.getId()

But the errror that i get is this

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'net' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Web3` with capital `W`, I'm assuming it's the name of the class - not the instance.

You need to access the **instance** property `net` and it's method `getId()`.

```
// instantiate the class first
const web3 = new Web3();

// mind the lowercase `w` in `web3`, accessing the instance
const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
```